# Assigning Label a value with for statement

Tags: c#, for-loop

Im getting an error "The Best overloaded method match for System.Web.UI.ControllerCollection.This[int] has some invalid arguments"

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; i++)
    {
        Label1.Text = Controls[string.Format("My Items: {0}", mylist[i]);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thank You!

Comment: `Controls[]` expects an `int` and not a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a string to the ControllerCollection. You need to pass an index within that collection.

Are you sure you don't want to just write:

```
Label1.Text = string.Format("My Items: {0}", mylist.Count);
```

??

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean

```
Label1.Text = string.Format("My Items: {0}", mylist[i]);
```

Although this will keep overwriting `Label1.Text`.